# CSS background-image path

Tags: css

I have a hard time adding picture through background-image property in css
my file structure looks like this:

```
www
   styles
      stylesheet.css
   images
      background.jpg
```

I tried:

```
background-image: url("/images/background.jpg");
background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
background-image: url("background.jpg");
background-image: url("../images/background.jpg");
background-image: url("/../images/background.jpg");
background-image: url("../../images/background.jpg");
```

I also tried all of these options without quotes. I copy-pasted image's name and my folders are as I stated: main folder in which I have styles folder(inside is stylesheet.css) and images folder (inside is background.jpg). The image did not load in chrome or firefox. What path declaration should I use to make the image show?

Comment: `../images/background.jpg` looks right; maybe the image isn’t showing up for a different reason. Could you show the full CSS rule and the HTML for the element you’re trying to apply it to?

Comment: When you inspect element (Chrome of FireFox), there should be an error for the image.  Check that and see what path the page is actually getting.  Once you know what the page is actually getting, it should be fairly simple to pinpoint what is going wrong.

Comment: Did the style sheet load at all? Do you see other styles from the same sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
www
   index.html
   styles
      stylesheet.css
   images
      background.jpg
```

that the directory, here inside index.html / index.php (where u want show)

```
<link href="styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

remember for href link
and then at stylesheet.css

```
background-image: url("../images/background.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background-image: url("../images/background.jpg");
```

This is correct. If it is not working, perhaps the path name is not the problem.

- Are you running this from a server?
- Or, are you running this from your computer?

Try changing the situation and see if anything changes.

I'd put my money on spelling mistake, though. Best to triple check it.

Comment: I triple checked every single letter one by one I am running this from localhost on wamp tried your suggested line of code, no success